# Give a Redshift Cluster access to S3 bucket owned by another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to unload data from Redshift to S3 using iam_role. The unload command works fine as long as I am unloading data to a S3 bucket owned by the same account as the Redshift cluster.

However, if I try to unload data into a S3 bucket owned by another account it doesn't work. I have tried the approach mentioned in these tutorials:

- [Tutorial: Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)
- [Example: Bucket Owner Granting Cross-Account Bucket Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html#access-policies-walkthrough-cross-account-permissions-acctA-tasks)

However, I always get `S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,Rid`

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I got it to work.** Here's what I did:

- Created an **IAM Role** in Account A that has `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy (for testing)
- Launched an **Amazon Redshift cluster** in Account A
- Loaded data into the Redshift cluster
- **Test 1:** Unload to a bucket in Account A -- **success**
- **Test 2:** Unload to a bucket in Account B -- **fail**
- Added a **bucket policy** to the bucket in Account B (see below)
- **Test 3:** Unload to a bucket in Account B -- **success!**

This is the bucket policy I used:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy11",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PermitRoleAccess",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Redshift-loader"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The `Redshift-loader` role was already associated with my Redshift cluster. This policy grants the role (that lives in a different AWS account) access to this S3 bucket.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe you did all of that in like 10 mins.

Comment: I was doing the same thing except instead of `"Action": "s3:*"` I had  `"Action": "s3:PutObject"`. After seeing your answer I started adding permission to the role one by one. Finally it worked at `"Action": ["s3:PutObject", "s3:List*"]`. Apparently, Redshift also needs list permissions to see if the items already exist in the bucket or not. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @John Rotenstein I am doing the same thing, but when I am creating the policy, I am getting this error: 'This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal'. Any reason why I am getting that?

Comment: @doctore Please create a new question rather than asking a question as a comment on an old question. (By the way, if you are putting a policy on an IAM entity such as a User or Role, then you do not need a `Principal`. It is, however, needed if you are creating a Bucket Policy).

Answer (score -2):

I solved it using access_key_id and secret_access_key instead iam_rol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please include some context and code samples with your answer as well as tie it into the original question's references.